# Selected option tag using Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have an Items collection with a boxId field (and a Boxes collection), and I want to be able to, through a **select tag**, change an item's boxId.

Here's my template:

[image: Template]

And this is how I define the boxOptions helper:

[image: boxOptions definition]

How can I get an item's boxId and use it to find the proper **option tag**, and then give it the **selected** attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Create an event

```
Template.item.helpers({
  "change select": function(event){
    const boxId = event.target.value;
    items.update({_id: this._id}, {$set: {boxId: boxId}});
  }
})
```

Note this assumes you are using the packages insecure and autopublish. If you don't use these and you really should not, then you best read about:

- Parameter validation
- Publications
- Meteor Methods

Comment: I'm already able to update the field. The problem is that the selected option tag is always the first one rendered. So I think I need to put a "selected" attribute on the proper option tag. That's my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `Template.parentData()` to have access to the item's id. Here's the helper:

```
selected: function () {
  if (this._id == Template.parentData().boxId) {
    return "selected";
  }
}
```